# Hive, count row multiple times and pivot in the same query

Tags: sql, hive

We are in the process of moving logs from Oracle to Hadoop on AWS and querying  in with Hive SQL.

The logs looks roughly like this

```
Log_table
Err_Id  System_Id, Err_time, Err_text
1       System 1   23:54      Err1 other text Err1
2       System 2   02:12      Err1 other text Err2
3       System 3   22:10      Err1
4       System 2   02:37      Err2
```

One of the desired outputs reports the number of events for each system by hour that include a given error code, so an error text that includes Err1 and Err2 would be counted in both but Err1 and Err1  in the same err_id would only be counted once.

```
Err 1
System    Hour
          0  1  2  3 ...22 23 
System 1  0  0  0  0 ... 0  1  
System 2  0  0  1  0 ... 0  0  
System 3  0  0  0  0 ... 1  0  

Err 2
System    Hour
          0  1  2  3 ...22 23
System 1  0  0  0  0 ... 0  0
System 2  0  0  2  0 ... 0  0
System 3  0  0  0  0 ... 0  0
```

I can create multiple queries and run separately or use union but although easy to code they are inefficient. eg

```
select 'err1' as error_type,
       system_id,
       sum(case when hour(Err_time)='00' then 1 else 0 end) as Hour00,
       sum(case when hour(Err_time)='10' then 1 else 0 end) as Hour01,
       ...
from Log_table
where instr(Err_text,'Err1')>0
group by 'err1', system_id
union
select 'err2' as error_type,
       system_id,
       sum(case when hour(Err_time)='00' then 1 else 0 end) as Hour00,
       sum(case when hour(Err_time)='10' then 1 else 0 end) as Hour01,
       ...
from Log_table
Where instr(Err_text,'Err2')>0
group by 'err2', system_id
```

I can also run a single pass and get the results with data in the wrong format and re-pivot it externally. e.g.

```
select system_id,
       hour(Err_time) as Err_hour,
       sum(case when instr(Err_text,'Err1')>0 then 1 else 0 end) as Err1,
       sum(case when instr(Err_text,'Err2')>0 then 1 else 0 end) as Err2,
       sum(case when instr(Err_text,'Err3')>0 then 1 else 0 end) as Err3
from Log_table
group by system_id,
         hour(Err_time)
```

Am I missing a neat and efficient way to do it in one pass?

Comment: Probably worth pointing out that, on the assumption I am going to be prevented from creating cartesian products that there may not be an elegant solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This version will not be much more efficient, but it is more concise:

```
select e.error_type,
       l.system_id,
       sum(case when hour(l.Err_time) = '00' then 1 else 0 end) as Hour00,
       sum(case when hour(l.Err_time) = '10' then 1 else 0 end) as Hour01,
       ...
from Log_table l join
     (select 'err1', 1 as ord as error_type union all
      select 'err2', 2 as ord as error_type
     ) e
     on instr(l.Err_text, e.error_type) > 0
group by e.error_type, system_id
order by ord, system_id;
```

You can also phrase the `from` as:

```
from ((select 'err1' as error_type, l.*
       from Log_table l 
       where instr(l.Err_text, 'err1') > 0
      ) union all
      (select 'err2' as error_type, l.*
       from Log_table l 
       where instr(l.Err_text, 'err2') > 0
      ) 
     ) l
```

That is, do the `union all` first and then the aggregation only one time.

Comment: Thank you, it looks like it should work but I have had to go back to my admin to ask for cartesian protection to be turned off "please sethive.strict.checks.cartesian.product to false" and to set hive.mapred.mode=nonstrict  Currently I'm am being told no.  I have upvoted as it is helpful but I've a less than 15 reputation so it doens't show up.